# Como fazer conteudo da input apareçer no alert?

Tags: input, button

Para exemplificar o que eu quero, é tipo eu escrever algo na *input* e quando apertar no botão, aparecer, no `alert`, o texto que eu escrevi.

**No JavaScript:**

```
    function myFunction (){

        var input = document.querySelector('.inputt');
        var text = document.createTextNode('');
        b_i.innerHTML = textt;

        alert(textt);
    }
```

**No *HTML*:**

```
   <input class='inputt'/>
   <button onclick='myFunction'></button>
```

Comment: `alert( document.querySelector('.inputt').value )`

Comment: vlw mano vc num tem ideia do quanto de tempo tava querendo isso kk

Answer (score 2):

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="inputId">
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" onclick="MyFunction()">
```

**JS**

```
function MyFunction(){
    var id = document.getElementById("inputId").value;
    alert(id);
}
```

Comment: Valeu amigo não tava sabendo usar direito esse .value por que tava testando em getclassname, queryselector e outros mais descobrir que so pega em algums, vou continuar testando pra eu pegar as manha.
abraços.☺☻